# kdeinit5 starts background konsoles with high CPU usage

Tags: kde, console, kubuntu

I am using KDE Neon LTS 5.12, sometimes, for some unknown reason, I can see a high CPU usage that comes from started konsoles by kdeinit5.

Every konsole has no window and uses up to 17% CPU approximately. As I do not know the reason this happens, sometimes I see one, or two, or 4 konsoles (17% * 4 = 68% CPU usage) with the same description: `konsole [kdeinit5]`.

[image: konsole [kdeinit5] problem]

It says I am the user who started these, but I do not know what do I do that makes this happen.

If I try to `[Jump to the parent process]` in the context menu, It redirects me to the obvious `kdeinit5: Running...` process.

[image: konsole [kdeinit5] problem]

I have been checking forums but did not found a solution yet.

#### UPDATE (2018-04-17)

I am still testing, I have already installed the same distribution with almost the same configuration in a laptop, with **just one difference: did not install the Nvidia drivers** both my desktop computer (the main PC used in this post) and the laptop are using Nvidia GPUs.

For some reason (again), seems to work perfectly well, without lefting processes in background nor initializing new ones.

Obviously, there is a performance loss that can be slightly recovered by setting the composer to `Xrender`, but even...

Is reported some kind of error related to this? I have tried other distros, but not as much to tell if this error is reproduced in those as well.

Will keep testing.

Comment: Appears related to this: https://askubuntu.com/q/964590/362789

Comment: @Geremia Maybe there are related somehow, but I do not run any server on my desktop computer so I do not know how to continue testing.

Comment: It's associated with Akonaki, not with an http server. What's the parent process of your kdeinit5 process? What's that process's full command? (`top` or `htop` will give you more details than `ksysguard`.)

Comment: Seems to not be more info: `/usr/bin/konsole` with `/bin/bash` associated, what is obvious.

Comment: I think you're right about https://askubuntu.com/q/964590/362789 not necessarily being related to your question. I uninstalled Akonadi and am still getting your issue (in my case, it's several "http.so" processes like: `http.so [kdeinit5] http local:/tmp/xdg-runtime-geremia/klauncherTJ9392.1` etc. that are related to Ktorrent).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution but a workaround.

After a dist-upgrade from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 I had the same issue, with the only difference that the `konsole` was taking a full core (25%) on close. Also, on the tree view you could see one process being terminated, re-appearing under `systemd` and then hanging...

I have changed the launcher of Konsole (KMenu->Right Click->Edit Applications...->Tab: Application) to have the following command:

```
konsole --nofork &
```

So, to my understanding I am asking `konsole` to not fork itself, instead the fork is happening with `&`. Until now (~1 hour) things seem to work as expected.

I am keen to see if there is a real fix for this one - but for now I am saving a core.